# How to find the minimum system requirements needed for the program I wrote in the C language?

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

I wrote a program in the C language. Now I want to make the system documentation for that program. And, I would like to state the minimum system requirements that are needed to run my my program.

How do I find out what they are?

Comment: Measure its CPU and memory usage.

Comment: You should have an idea about the time and space complexities, and you should have benchmarked and profiled your program (after having it compiled with optimizations enabled). Then you can know the memory resources required. Likewise for file space.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can do:

Try running your app on the oldest machines you can find.

Remove a couple memory sticks from your computer

Do you have a define _WIN32_WINNT  in your application? If not, the windows SDK you use will define the minimum OS requirement.

You can also try compiling with -D_WIN32_WINNT=xx for an older version to see how far back you can go, based on the Windows API calls you use.  windows.h is pretty good at hiding APIs for versions newer than the one you specify with _WIN32_WINNT. Then keep that setting to compile your app to create test and release binaries.

Here's the MS doc on versioning with _WIN32_WINNT: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa383745

Silly me!  I forgot to add that you MUST test on the oldest version you specify in your specs + the one most used by your target users.